# Setup and Testing to prevent duplication in ActiveRecord many to many relationship

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the following classes for a many to many relationship between "Item" and "Color".

And "Item" should not have duplicated "Colors", 
for example:-
If "Item1" has "Blue" & "Red" then we cannot add another "Red" to "Item1"

Is this the correct way to set this up?

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :item_colors  
    has_many :colors, :through => item_colors  
end  

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_colors
    has_many :items, :through => item_colors
end

class ItemColor < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :color

    validates_uniqueness_of :color, scope: :item
end
```

My Test for duplicated colors. Is it how to test it?

```
describe "item should not have duplicated colors" do
    before do
        @item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
        @color1 = FactoryGirl.create(:color)
        @item.colors << @color1
        @item.colors << @color1
        @item.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

When I try this in rails console, it will fail when I add duplcated color to an item
but instead of getting an error message in `item.errors.message`, I got an ActiveRecord exception

```
"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Color has already been taken"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the second color, it is [automatically saved](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference-when-are-objects-saved-questionmark) because the parent object `@item` is already saved, i.e. it is not a `new_record`.

Given it is a `has_many :through` association, it is [**always** saved with the bang version of `save!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L93), which in turn raises the exception because your join model `ItemColor` fails on the validation of uniqueness.

In your case you have two options:

1. `rescue` the exception and manage the error messages manually or;
2. if you're using a join model just to add the validation layer, you could get rid of it, use a [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) instead and handle the association as a set, e.g.

   ```
   > item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
   > color = FactoryGirl.create(:color)
   > 10.times { item.colors |= [color] } # you can add it n times...
   > item.colors.count # => 1  ...still only one is saved b/c it is a union set.
   ```

How does that sound to you?

**UPDATE:** In case you really want to show an error message, you could, e.g.

```
if item.colors.include?(color)
  item.errors.add(:colors, "color already selected")
else
  item.colors |= [color]
end
```

Comment: @snackmoore did this help you in any way?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was unable to login for a few days due the open id problem. I like 2 option, but how would I alert user with error message?

Comment: I think you don't need an error message. Even if the user tries to add the same colour more than once, the system will always save only one because it's acting like a set. In terms of user experience, IMHO, the error message can be suppressed, most likely b/c users will try to add the an existing colour by mistake. Eventually their action will have the expected result and no error will be raised. Nevertheless, should you really want to warn your users, I've updated the answer with a sample solution.